# Imaginary Eigenvectors and Systems

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

NOTE: This is a homework problem (not graded). I want to *learn* how to do this math problem, not just be given an answer. Thank you for any help you can give!

So, in this problem I am dealing with trajectories of a system when eigenvalues are purely imaginary. It is stated in the homework problem that the trajectories are as follows:

`(x)'  (a11 a12)(x)
(y) = (a21 a22)(y)`

*These are matrices.

Question `A.)` states:

```
Show that the eigenvalues are of the coefficient matrix are purely imaginary if and only if:
a11 + a22 = 0, 
a11*a22 - a12*a21 > 0
```

My work for `A.)`:

```
λ^2 - trace(A)λ + determinant(A);
λ^2 - (a11+a12)λ + (a11*a22 - a12*a21);
```

Next I find the zeros to solve for the eigenvalues. This proves that the eigenvalues MUST be imaginary (I believe). I use the quadratic formula, but ignore the division by `2*a` because it is irrelevant in determining if the system is imaginary or not..

```
(a11+a22) ± √[(a11+a22)^2 - 4(1)(a11*a22 - a12*a21)]
```

We assume that `a11 + a22 = 0` and `a11*a22 - a12*a21 > 0`
I now plug in the 0 for all `a11 + a22`:

```
0 ± √[(0)^2 - 4(1)(a11*a22 - a12*a21)]
± √[-4(a11*a22 - a12*a21)]
```

Now if `a11*a22 - a12*a21 > 0`, than it necessarily follows that the system's trajectory is imaginary.

Question `B.)` states:

`dy/dx = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt) = (a21*x + a22*y)/(a11*x + a12*y)`
`Use a11 + a12 = 0 to show that this is exact.`

For this question, do I purely plug in dx/dt and dy/dt, respectively? I am not sure how to prove this is 'exact'.

Question `C.)` states:

By integrating the last equations show that `a12*x^2 + 2*a22*x*y + a12*y^2 = k` where `k` is constant. Use the equations:

```
a11 + a22 = 0, 
a11*a22 - a12*a21 > 0
```

to show that the graph is always an ellipse.

How can I show that this is ALWAYS an ellipse? Do I just integrate the system and work it until I come to `a12*x^2 + 2*a22*x*y + a12*y^2 = k`?

Comment: @Amzoti I meant to put into the question that I ignored the division by 2 because it is irrelevant to the problem. I am just proving the eigenvalues are imaginary. However, you are correct that I technically should have written the division by 2.

Comment: @Amzoti so, you are saying that my A.) is correct? How would the **2** make a difference? I am a little confused.

Comment: @Amzoti alright, I understand what you are saying. So the answer would end up being: `±i*√[(a11*a22 - a12*a21)]` for `A.)`

Comment: @Amzoti exactly, thank you for supporting my finds for part `A.)` Would you happen to be able to help me with `B.)` or `C.)`